# Running docker comand on server doesn't work

Tags: typescript, docker, docker-compose

I am currently working on a new project. I need an api that runs with Docker from Github (https://github.com/PoloLacoste/r6-api). only i have a problem, it doesn't work.

when I execute this command, the server works for 4 seconds and then it terminates

docker run --name r6-api -e EMAIL=EMAIL -e PASSWORD=PASSWORD -e PORT=3000 -p 3000:3000 -d pololacoste/r6-api

can anyone help me?

it's best someone explain me the steps to setup, because i don't know docker that much.

Comment: have you checked for errors on the console?  Docker compose can be a bit noisy, so you might want to read from the bottom up.  sounds to me like the application is failing to initialize itself.  You might want to add tags to the question about the language -typescript?

Comment: no problem, added

Comment: no errors occur

Comment: When I run it, it fails with `[PackageLoader] The "class-transformer" package is missing. Please, make sure to install this library ($ npm install class-transformer) to take advantage of ValidationPipe.`. To me that looks like the image isn't in a condition where it can run.

Comment: when i installed this docker run my steps were:  clone dir, install docker and run the comand. or am I wrong?